# get value from inside object

Tags: javascript

Here is my JSON [object](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=31d249b34c64a364e30a3adf2b766b86).

```
[{"dataset": {"item": [{"key1": "'key1'","key2": "value1"},
                   {"key1": "'key1'","key2": "value2"},
                   {"key1": "'key1'","key2": "value3"}]}},
 {"dataset": {"dataset": { "dataset": { "item": [{"key1": "key1","key2": "value4"}]}}}}]
```

How to get `'key2'` value from all nodes. In object still it have more nodes.

Comment: A bit broad. Try to limit to a specific question. Else, it is a *very basic* question about JSON

Comment: Traverse all nodes and collect `key2` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the [custom reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter)

```js
var json = `[{"dataset": {"item": [{"key1": "'key1'","key2": "value1"},
                   {"key1": "'key1'","key2": "value2"},
                   {"key1": "'key1'","key2": "value3"}]}},
 {"dataset": {"dataset": { "dataset": { "item": [{"key1": "key1","key2": "value4"}]}}}}]`

var result = []

// Traverse all nodes and collect key2 values.
JSON.parse(json, function(key, value) {
  if (key === 'key2') {
    result.push(value)
  }
  if (key === 'item') {
    console.log(value)
  }
  return value
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: how to get value of key 'item', i changed it,but not working as expected

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with Object.keys and traverse the nodes recursively.

```js
var json = [{"dataset": {"item": [{"key1": "'key1'","key2": "value1"},
                   {"key1": "'key1'","key2": "value2"},
                   {"key1": "'key1'","key2": "value3"}]}},
 {"dataset": {"dataset": { "dataset": { "item": [{"key1": "key1","key2": "value4"}]}}}}];
 
let res = [];
for(prop in json){
  const recursive = (obj, targetKey) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
      if (key === targetKey) {
          res.push(obj[key]);
      } else {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
          recursive(obj[key], targetKey);
        }
      }
    });
  };
  
  recursive(json[prop], 'key2');
}
console.log('res', res)
```

Comment: how to get value of key 'item', i changed as `recursive(json[prop], 'item');`but not working as expected

Comment: @Durga, thats because the key 'item' is an object and not a key/value pair, the question was to find a key inside a nested object.

Comment: can you give a hint, how to get that as well

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to get back the item arrays? Or are you trying to find a key item inside the item array? @Durga

Comment: I need `[{"key1": "key1","key2": "value4"}]` total array if i pass key as `item`

Comment: Okey, just switch the statement inside the loop @Durga